# Divergence of a function product with functions in $L^\infty (\Omega)$ and $H^1(\Omega)$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, distribution-theory, weak-derivatives

I am doing the weak formulation of the equation:

$\nabla ( k \nabla u) = f \ \text{in } \Omega$

I want to find the correct space for k in order to have $\nabla ( k \nabla u)$ well defined.
At the moment, I am sure that I have to require $u\in H^2(\Omega)$ during the process to be able to use the Green's formula (or even the Stoke's theorem). Also, I think it is needed that $k\nabla u\in H^1(\Omega)$ in order to have the divergence correctly defined. First of all, I impose $k\in L^\infty(\Omega)$ so $k\nabla u\in L^2(\Omega)$. Does this condition also imply that $k\nabla u\in H^1(\Omega)$?

I was thinking on $k\in W^{1,\infty}(\Omega)$ to have this product well defined, but my professor told me that we can assume that the strong formulation allows us to have well defined the divergence of that product.

I am not sure if I need to impose derivatives of $k$ in $L^\infty (\Omega)$ to have everything well defined, or just think this derivative in the way of distributions and impose $k\in L^\infty(\Omega)$.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Let me reach a bit further back.

Your notation is a bit sloppy, which may mislead and thus confuse you. The correct expression for the differential operator is $\nabla \cdot (k \nabla u) = \operatorname{div} (k \nabla u)$, i.e. the divergence of $k \nabla u$, while $\nabla (k \nabla u)$ would denote the gradient of the vector field $k \nabla u$, i.e. the derivative in all directions (the Jacobian). This distinction is important because requiring $\operatorname{div}(k \nabla u)$ to be well-defined is a much weaker condition than requiring $\nabla(k \nabla u)$ to be well-defined. In the following I assume you wanted to ask what conditions are necessary for $\operatorname{div}(k \nabla u)$ to be well-defined.

To be nit-picky (or maybe not), you must specify in which sense that expression should be well-defined. I assume you meant that $\operatorname{div}(k \nabla u) \in L^2(\Omega)$ since then, under the additional assumption that $f \in L^2(\Omega)$, one can say that the differential equation $\operatorname{div}(k \nabla u(x)) = f(x)$ holds for $x \in \Omega$ almost everywhere.

If you don't assume from the get-go that $k \nabla u \in (H^1(\Omega))^d$ then the question arises what $\operatorname{div}(k \nabla u) \in L^2(\Omega)$ should even mean. You stated in your comments that you never found a use for distributional derivatives, so this is a good time as any to make use of those concepts (and maybe clear up some more confusion). For any vector field $v \in (L^2(\Omega))^d$, with the special case $v = k \nabla u$ in mind, the distributional divergence of $v$ is the distribution $\operatorname{div} v \in C^\infty_0(\Omega)'$ defined by
$$ [\operatorname{div} v](\varphi) := -\int_{\Omega} v \cdot \nabla \varphi \, \mathrm dx \quad \forall \varphi \in C^\infty_0(\Omega). $$

This mirrors the definition of the distributional derivatives which you should already know. Indeed, you can define the distributional version of any linear differential operator in a similar way. It's important to realize that while this may look like "just" partial integration / Green's identities, the basic idea of distributional derivatives is that the right-hand side is well-defined even if only $v \in (L^2(\Omega))^d$ and nothing more. Only if $v$ is more regular, partial integration allows us to a-posteriori identify the distributional derivative with more a classical function. This identification of distributional divergence is done (as for distributional derivatives) by saying that $\operatorname{div} v \in C^\infty_0(\Omega)'$ is represented by a function $h \in L^2(\Omega)$ if there holds
$$ \int_{\Omega} h \varphi \,\mathrm dx = v(\varphi) \left( = -\int_{\Omega} v \cdot \nabla \varphi \, \mathrm dx \right)$$
for all $\varphi \in C^\infty_0(\Omega)$. One then, casually one may say, writes $\operatorname{div} v = h$. This is the sense in which $\operatorname{div} v \in L^2(\Omega)$, e.g. $\operatorname{div}(k \nabla u) \in L^2(\Omega)$, must be understood. Of course one could just say that a vector field $v$ has "a divergence
in $L^2(\Omega)$" if there is a $h \in L^2(\Omega)$ satisfying this equation without ever mentioning "distribution" or "distributional derivative", but this hides the generality of the ideas behind the construction.

With this preparation, I claim that $k \in L^\infty(\Omega)$ is sufficient that any solution $u \in H^1(\Omega)$ of your weak equation
$$ \int_\Omega k \nabla u \cdot \nabla \varphi \,\mathrm dx = \int_\Omega f \varphi \,\mathrm dx $$
for all $\varphi \in H^1_0(\Omega)$ with $f \in L^2(\Omega)$ has regularity $\operatorname{div}(k \nabla u) \in L^2(\Omega)$. Comparing the integral equation for the weak solution with the condition I wrote above for $h \in L^2(\Omega)$ to represent the distributional derivative of $\operatorname{div}(k \nabla u)$, you can see that $h = - f$ and if $f \in L^2(\Omega)$ thus $\operatorname{div}(k \nabla u) \in L^2(\Omega)$. The regularity $k \in L^\infty(\Omega)$ is here only used such that $v = k \nabla u \in L^2(\Omega)$ (and of course for less regular $k$ the integral equation for the weak solutions is no longer well-defined for $\varphi \in H^1_0(\Omega))$). This argument of course only works because $u$ is not any function in $H^1(\Omega)$ but one that satisfies the integral equation, which gives you the regularity $\operatorname{div}(k \nabla u) \in L^2(\Omega)$ "for free" if your right-hand side $f$ has that regularity.

As a last note, the space of vector fields $v \in (L^2(\Omega))^d$ with $\operatorname{div} v \in L^2(\Omega)$ is typically denoted by $H(\operatorname{div}; \Omega)$, thus $k \nabla u \in H(\operatorname{div}; \Omega)$ is the minimal regularity for $\operatorname{div}(k \nabla u)$ to be well-defined.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you would need $k \nabla u \in H^1$ to have these defined directly. Assuming that $k \in L^\infty$ and $\nabla u \in H^1$ in general isn't enough to make the product in $H^1$ (take $k$ to be very not-differentiable, but still bounded, and take $\nabla u$ to be nonzero where $k$ is badly behaved). However, you could assume the weaker condition that $k \nabla u \in L^2$, and then define $\nabla (k \nabla u)$ weakly by the formula
$$
\int_\Omega \phi \nabla(k \nabla u)\, dx = -\int_\Omega \nabla \phi \cdot k \nabla u\, dx
$$
for all $\phi$ smooth and compactly supported in $\Omega$ (or all $\phi \in H^1_0(\Omega))$. The condition $k\nabla u \in L^2$, for instance, would follow if $u \in H^1$ and $k \in L^\infty$.

When doing weak formulation of PDE, it is usually this second approach that is used. The unknown $u$ is generally required to be $H^1(\Omega)$ (or $H^1_0(\Omega)$ if we have Dirichlet boundary conditions), and the coefficients $k$ may by $L^\infty$ or whatever we suppose for the problem.

Comment: This seems to be the way to do it. But I have always worked with weak formulations by using the Green's formula. I know about the generalization of derivatives for distributions but I have never found a practical use of them. How does this new term $w$ relate to Green's formula? Does this new term take into account the values in the boundary?

Comment: Apologies - the $w$ was a typo from my scratchwork. I've fixed it now. One solves the Dirichlet boundary condition problem first and then works from there (Section 6.2 of Evans goes into this, also). The use of this formulation is that it allows you to reformulate a PDE as a problem with a bilinear form on a Hilbert space, and then we can throw functional analysis theorems at it.